# Parsing Geoserver WMS log in Logstash

Tags: tomcat, logstash, geoserver, wms

What does the configuration for a logstash pipeline look like to parse a geoserver wms log. An example request looks like.

```
2016-03-21 09:21:53,833 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
        Filter = null
        Palette = null
        Tiled = false
        SRS = EPSG:3857
        FeatureVersion = null
        Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=polygon]]
        Filters = null
        Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@f944d59a]
        MaxFeatures = null
        Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
        Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-8380176.806709324 : -8344030.356053375, 4846475.643831644 : 4886000.4896522565]
        RemoteOwsType = null
        RemoteOwsURL = null
        Env = {}
        FormatOptions = {}
        Angle = 0.0
        CQLFilter = null
        Elevation = []
        FeatureId = null
        StartIndex = null
        ViewParams = null
        BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
        Transparent = false
        StyleFormat = sld
        SldBody = null
        ValidateSchema = false
        Sld = null
        StyleUrl = null
        Interpolations = []
        TilesOrigin = null
        Exceptions = SE_XML
        StyleBody = null
        SldVersion = null
        StyleVersion = null
        ScaleMethod = null
        Width = 702
        Height = 768
        Buffer = 0
        Format = application/openlayers
        Time = []
        Request = GetMap
        Get = true
        RawKvp = {BBOX=-8380176.806709324,4846475.643831644,-8344030.356053375,4886000.4896522565, VERSION=1.1.0, FORMAT=application/openlayers, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=768, REQUEST=GetMap, LAYERS=geog585:Neighborhoods, STYLES=, WIDTH=702, SRS=EPSG:3857}
        BaseUrl = http://localhost:8082/geoserver/
        RequestCharset = UTF-8
        Version = 1.1.0
```

I have looked at the WMS plugin available through Logstash and can't seem to get it to parse correctly. My current configuration looks as follows:

```
input { 
    file {
        type => "tomcat"
        path => [ "/Applications/GeoServer.app/Contents/Java/data_dir/logs/*.log"  ]
        codec => multiline {
          pattern => "(^\d+\serror)|(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)"
          what => "previous"
        }
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
# Tomcat filter
  if [type] == "tomcat" and [message] !~ /(.+)/ {
    drop { }
  }
  wms {}
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean that it won't parse correctly?  The first step is to make sure your multiline is working correctly and you see a good [message] field from your stdout{} output.  For your multiline, you should check out the 'negate' option so you can say "any line that do not start with a date should be joined to the previous".

Comment: I have updated my multiline function so that now works 

multiline {
          patterns_dir => "/Users/samchorlton/Documents/GeoServerLogProcessing/Apps/LogstashPlugins/grok-patterns"
          pattern => "(^%{URIHOST} %{TIME})|(^%{CATALINA_DATESTAMP})"
          negate => true
          what => "previous"
        }

But it still errors whilst going through the WMS plugin for logstash just saying it cannot provided request URI.

Comment: The WMS plugin (seemingly a private addition) is expecting a URI, not a full message.  https://github.com/elastic/logstash-contrib/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/wms.rb#L64

Comment: I would go down a different path honestly.

Install the auditing extension (see here http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/configuration.html and here http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/auditing.html) and then chew those logs.